# Coding style and organization

Tags: java, class, design-patterns, methods, code-organization

So I am currently making a airplane reservation system for a summer project to keep fresh with Java. With any reservation system its requiring a lot of classes and methods. Currently I'm working on importing the fleet.

My main method is acting like the chronological guide to my program.

```
public static void main(String[] args){
    //start here 
    //accept passenger credentials 
    //place passenger in seat on plane
}
```

My question is a formatting problem. When I'm looking to start "making" my aircraft for my fleet. It goes a little like this.

```
//...
Airplane Boeing737 = new Airplane(seats[], nameOfAircraft);
```

This will put all values that i need to construct my airplane, obviously there are more variables for the airplane constructor.

My thought is to make a method in the Airplane class that will do this for me. but in order to do this i need to call a blank constructor for the other class (the one with my main method) to see it. I feel like this is horrible form for some reason. Is there a better way to do this?

Another thought as I'm posting is to modify the constructor to not accept any arguments and have that do everything in there. I feel like that's what I should be doing but I'm not 100% sure that would be the correct choice. I guess my overall question would be what are best practices in situations like this.

Comment: why don't you provide setters for seats and nameofAircraft ?

Comment: I strongly recommend at this point you need to do some reading about IS-A and HAS-A testing. Aircraft has AirPlane, AirPlane has Seats or Boeing737 is a AirPlane etc...

Comment: I don't quite get your second-to-last paragraph. Why would you have to provide a no-argument constructor for the class that contains `main()`?

Comment: How much do the airplanes vary? Do they have some default values or can each attribute be unique? If they always start with some common values, then you could use some design patterns (like prototype) and only pass in the values that are different. The best practice really depends on how you see the big picture with your details.

Comment: To construct your `Airplane` instances you could have a look at the builder and factory patterns.

Comment: @HRgiger I provide getters and setters for everything. The problem in my, i guess, style is that im using my main method and main class seperately. So in order to see different classes in my project I need to declare them

Comment: @Thomas my no argument constructor is for my Airplane() class that i am calling from my main method.

Comment: @memfisto the idea is exactly that, to provide all of the information that they share within the airplane class, then all the differences are dealt with inside the airplane class using a method. At least that's my idea.

Comment: In essence, what you should do depends. If this really your personal project, where you want to spend maybe 10, 20, 30 hours on ... then just go forward and focus on those areas that seem interesting to you. But: if you intend to really learn something about how to build "real things" ... then there are may too many things you have to learn. If the later is the case, you might want to turn to a book like "Agile principles" by Robert Martin (you can find the C# version of that book as free PDF on the net) and read almost all of that.

Comment: getters and setters are encapsulation which is another good practise, you will understand after some reading architectural design will make your job very easy i.e. abstract airplane can have constructor args but subclass boing737 doesnt need one. So after you can review builder pattern and start googling Kurt answer

Comment: @gemini88mill Then, as Thomas said, check Factory pattern, and you can go check Prototype pattern as well.

Comment: Thanks, Jordi answered my short term question, but @Kurt answered a more important question lol.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use builder pattern, this will allow you:

- dynamic way of building events
- maintainable code (you can add more params when you want)
- preserve integrity of the objects when created

---

Joshua Bloch's in Effective Java Chapter 1 Item 2 states:

> Luckily, there is a third alternative that combines the safety of the telescoping
>   constructor pattern with the readability of the JavaBeans pattern. It is a form of the
>   Builder pattern. Instead of making the desired object directly,
>   the client calls a constructor (or static factory) with all of the required parameters and gets a builder object.

Modifying his example:

```
//Builder Pattern
public class Airplane  {
    private final int[] seats;
    private final String name;
    private final int maxSpeed;
    private final int maxPassengers;

    public static class Builder {
        // Required parameters
        private final int[] seats;
        private final String name;

        // Optional parameters - initialized to default values
        private int maxSpeed = 1000;
        private int maxPassengers = 150;

        public Builder(int[] seats, String name) {
            this.seats = seats;
            this.name = name;
        }

        public Builder maxSpeed(int val) {
            maxSpeed = val;
            return this;
        }

        public Builder maxPassengers(int val) {
            maxPassengers = val;
            return this;
        }

        public Airplane build() {
            return new Airplane(this);
        }
    }

    private Airplane(Builder builder) {
        seats = builder.seats;
        name = builder.name;
        maxSpeed = builder.maxSpeed;
        maxPassengers = builder.maxPassengers;
    }
}
```

Then you can create several different airplanes

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    // only mandatory params
    Airplane boeing747  = new Airplane.Builder(new int[] {1,0,1}, "boeing747").build();
    // just one param
    Airplane boeing646  = new Airplane.Builder(new int[] {1,1,1}, "boeing646").maxPassengers(250).build();
    // all params
    Airplane fighter    = new Airplane.Builder(new int[] {1,0,0}, "fighter_1").maxPassengers(3).maxSpeed(1600).build();
}
```

Comment: this is great, so if i understand correctly. the builder class kinda makes the variables from the class itself. 

For example, before Airplane i have Flight and Flightpath and i can use that to build the entire flight instead of starting at the bottom 

e.g. passenger -> seat -> Airplane -> Flight -> Airline etc etc

Comment: @gemini88mill yes sure, just define the builder accepting the parameters you need, don't worry if there are your own objects or primitive ones.

Answer (score 2):

Forget the main method for now, you don't know if it will be a command line program, desktop app with a UI, web service or what. You don't know if it will be standalone or hosted in some framework or application server.

I would suggest starting with unit tests and drive the design of your domain model / business logic with TDD.

You don't want to see anything like Boeing737 hard coded like that. It will get its input from some other source, e.g. typed in, xml file, existing database, some other system.

You will then create instances of Airplane dynamically. You will pass something like a DTO from the UI or DB or XML parser to the constructor. There are other ways, look up Factory Pattern for example, but they tend to get overused IMHO.

You seem to be starting off in a way that doesn't match anything anyone does in the real world. Its hard to give any better advice.

Comment: This is super insightful thank you. the main idea is to get a better grasp of classes and methods and tactics on new and interesting ways to build them. 

You are correct the final idea for my code would be that the program would get information from an outside source It would make any sense to have airplane models hard coded. 

I am super new to unit testing, is there a good tutorial you can point me to?